# Function to copy a file using sendfile

Tags: beginner, c

I've just found out there is `sendfile()`. In the man page of [`sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html), it says:

> `sendfile()` is more efficient than the combination of `read(2)` and `write(2)`.

So, I wrote a function to copy a file using `sendfile()`.

Is really my code more efficient than the combination of `read(2)` and `write(2)`?

```
/* leftsize is initialized with total size of source file. */
fd_src = open(src_fname, O_RDONLY);
if (fd_src<0){
    printf("open failed(%s)\n", src_fname);
    return -1;
}
fd_dest = creat(dest_fname, 0666);
if (fd_dest<0){
    printf("create failed(%s)\n", dest_fname);
    return -1;
}
while (leftsize > 0) {
    n = sendfile(fd_dest, fd_src, NULL, max_size);
    if (n<0) {
        printf("sendfile failed. ret:%d errno:%d\n", n, errno);
    }
    leftsize -= n;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first paragraph of the man page says it all:

> `sendfile()` copies data between one file descriptor and another.
>          Because this copying is done within the kernel, `sendfile()` is more
>          efficient than the combination of `read(2)` and `write(2)`, which would
>          require transferring data to and from user space.

So, `sendfile` is quite efficient.

However, your loop *may* use `sendfile` incorrectly because you *always* try to transfer `max_size` and this could return an error (`EOVERFLOW`) on the *last* chunk of the file (i.e. you try to read *more* than remains in the input file).

This *may* work just fine if you handle the error case properly.

It also depends upon what `max_size` and `leftsize` actually are [which you didn't specify].

I'll assume that `max_size` is some reasonable chunk limit (e.g. `max_size = 1024 * 1024;`) and that `leftsize` is the size of the input file that comes from:

```
struct stat st;
fstat(fd_src,&st);
leftsize = st.st_size;
```

So, just to be safe, here is what I'd do:

```
while (leftsize > 0) {
    // get chunk size
    n = max_size;

    // clip transfer size to remainder of file
    if (n > leftsize)
        n = leftsize;

    n = sendfile(fd_dest, fd_src, NULL, n);
    if (n<0) {
        printf("sendfile failed. ret:%d errno:%d\n", n, errno);
    }

    leftsize -= n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you are testing the return values to see if your function calls succeeded.  However, it's good practice to use the **standard error** stream for your error messages:

```
if (fd_src<0){
    fprintf(stderr, "open failed(%s)\n", src_fname);
    return -1;
}
```

It's not clear whether the code is supposed to be in `main()` (next time, please post a complete function, and preferably a full, compilable program); if so, it's conventional to use **small positive numbers** for exit status.  Negative numbers can get truncated - on my system, a return of `-1` ends up as `255` when run from a shell.  If you return `+1` instead, that is received unscathed.